# ImportError: No module named telepot when working Telegram bot with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: internet

I am getting an error as

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/telegrambot.py", line 7, in 
import telepot
ImportError: No module named 'telepot'

But installed it using the command
sudo pip install telepot

what shall i do now?

Comment: What version of python are you using in your program?

Comment: Can you check if it installed correctly? "pip list | grep telepot"